# How to dissolve a subset of a multipolygon vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, dissolve, vector-layer

I have a multipolygon layer. Some of the polygons within the layer overlap. I would like to dissolve **only** the polygons which overlap and not any discrete polygons. Is this possible? I am currently using QGIS.

Comment: You can `dissolve` the whole layer, then use `multi- to single-part` in order to "separate" the non-overlapping polygons again. This removes all attributes, so you might have to `join attributes by location` in the end.

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work perfectly. Appreciate the help!